# KeyError: True for conditional indexing in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing two columns: one filled with a string (irrelevant), and the other one is (a reference to) a dataframe.

Now I want to only keep the rows, where the dataframes in the second column have entries aka `len(df.index) > 0` (there should be rows left, I don't care about columns).
I know that sorting out rows like this works perfectly fine for me if I use it in a list comprehension and can do it on every entry by its own, like in the following example:

```
[do_x for a, inner_df 
 in zip(outer_df.index, outer_df["inner"])
 if len(inner_df.index) > 0]
```

But if I try using it for conditional indexing to create a shorter version of the dataframe, it will produce the error `KeyError: True`.

I thought, that putting len() around it could be a problem so I also tried different approaches to check for zero rows. *In the following I show 4 examples of how I tried it*:

```
# a) with the length of the index
outer_df = outer_df.loc[len(outer_df["inner"].index) > 0, :]

# b) same, but with lambda just like in the panda docs user guide
# I used it on the other versions too, with no change in result
outer_df = outer_df.loc[lambda df: len(df["inner"]) > 0, :]

# c) switching
outer_df = outer_df.loc[outer_df["inner"].index.size > 0, :]

# d) even "shorter" version
outer_df = outer_df.loc[not outer_df["inner"].empty, :]
```

So... where is my error and can I even do it with conditional indexing or do I need to find another way?

---

Edit: Changed and added some sentences above for more clarity plus added all below.

I know, that the filtering here kind of works through creating a Series the same length as the dataframe consisting of "True" and "False" after a comparison, resulting in keeping only the rows that contain a "True".

I do not however see a fundamental difference between my attempt to create such a list and the following examples (Source https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selecting-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-conditions/):

```
# 1. difference: the resulting Series is *not* altered
# it just gets compared directly with here the value 80
# -> I thought this might be the problem, but then there is also #2
df = df[df['Percentage'] > 80]
# or
df = df.loc[df['Percentage'] > 80]

# 2. Here the entry is checked in a similar way to my c and d
options = ['x', 'y']
df = df[df['Stream'].isin(options)]
# or 
df = df.loc[df['Stream'].isin(options)]
```

In both, number two here and my versions c & d, the entry in the cell (string // dataframe) is checked for something (is part of list // is empty).

Comment: You need to show the part where you "try using it to create a shorter version of the dataframe with conditional indexing".

Comment: I would highly recommend you stop trying to solve this problem, but try to follow some examples in the doc and understand what `.loc` truely does. `.loc` requires a truth table, made of a `pd.Series` of df's indexes and boolean values.  You are feeding a single boolean value to it. All your examples are wrong in the same way.

Comment: @xyzjayne I marked it in my text: The four code lines were four of my attempts.

Comment: @eliu I know this and I added a second part to my question to make other thoughts of mine clear: I do not see the difference between my attempt in c and d compared to the second attempt of the examples at the end. So just like the #2 is checking the "underlying" string of the cell if it is an element of the options list, I would expect .empty to work on the "underlying" dataframe in that cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question or where you are stuck. however, I will just write my comment in this answer so that I can easily edit the post.

First, let's try typing in `myvar = df['Percentage'] > 80` and see what `myvar` is. See if the content of `myvar` makes sense to you.

There is really only 1 true rule of `.loc[]`, that is, the **TRUTH TABLE**.

Regarding the `df[stuff] expression` always appears within `.loc[ df[stuff] expression ]`, you might get the impression that `df[stuff] expression` had some special meaning. For example: `df[df['Percentage'] > 80]` is asking for any `Percentage` that is greater than 80, looks quite intuitive! so...`df['Percentage'] > 80` must be a "special syntax"? In reality, `df['Percentage'] > 80` isn't anything special, it is just another truth table. `df[stuff] expression` will always be a truth table, that's it.

Comment: The part about understanding that a truth table is the goal was not my problem. My problem (still) is understanding, why my version does not generate one while the example #2 does. But nevertheless your answer brought me to the solution I'm using now:

`truth = [True if len(inner_df.index) > 0 else False for inner_df in outer_df[„inner"]]`
`outer_df = outer_df.loc[truth]`

So thank you! :D

Comment: @Medsmiley Ok, I see the point now. Right, my bad, another rule about the truth table is that... all operators like `<`, `isin` etc **needs to support** vectorized operation. `.index` is not vectorized operation. To make things clearer, imagine you don't have dfs in second column, but just another of your own class objects,  say `car` objects.  `len(df['inner'].get_numberofseats())` won't look right anymore. The recommended solution would be `df['new_column'] = df['inner'].empty` then, `.loc` with the `new_column`.

Comment: wow, I fell in your trap too, `df['inner'].empty` is wrong. we need `apply()` or `agg` for this.